# Why the file is appending text instead of replacing its contents?

Tags: file, rust

I have a `struct` with a [File](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#) and another `struct` with other data inside. I have implemented a function to store de other data into the file:

```rust
    pub struct DataHandler {
        pub file: File,
        other_data: OtherData,
    }
    impl DataHandler {
        fn write_to_file(&mut self) {
            self.file
                .write_all(toml::to_string(&self.other_data).unwrap().as_ref())
                .unwrap();
        }
    }
```

When the `DataHandler` is created, the file is open with **read** and **write** permissions:

```rust
        let file = OpenOptions::new()
            .read(true)
            .write(true)
            .create(true)
            .open(file_path)
            .unwrap();
        ...

        let mut handler = DataHandler { file, other_data};
```

Whenever the `write_to_file` function is called, the data is **appended** to the file, although in the `write` [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.write) states that:

> If the file already exists, any write calls on it will overwrite its contents

The question is, why are the `write_all` calls appending data? Is it because the file is never closed (since `DataHandler` is never dropped)?

I tried store a `Path` variable instead of `File` inside `DataHandler` and open the file each time I want to write, but it seems to me pretty inefficient. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `write` (or `write_all`) will write to the current position of the `File` which is advanced with every `write`. Everything else would mean you have to always write the whole contents of the file all at once which wouldn't be very ergonomic.

You can [`seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.seek) to [`SeekFrom::Start(0)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.SeekFrom.html) before you want to start writing from the beginning again. You probably also want to [`File::set_len`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.set_len) to the amount of bytes you've written afterwards or you will end up with some left over bytes after the data you've written sooner or later.

What the documentation means is that `write` will start writing at the beginning instead of appending, it'll still advance the current position though.

Comment: `seek_from(SeekFrom::Start(0))` can be written as `rewind()`.